# Как перевести "I'm with stupid"

Tags: перевод

In South Park episodes, Kenny's mom usually wears a t-shirt which says "I'm with stupid", and an arrow pointing towards a person standing next to her.  How would you translate "I'm with stupid" into Russian?

Comment: thanks very much for your answer and explaining a Russian phrase  commonly used in a related situation! Indulgently agreeing with anything a stupid person says or does is often said in English as "whatever you say" or "sure, whatever".

Comment: Can you explain what this phrase mean? To me it makes no sense. Also, what article is supposed?

Comment: Either of those should make sense:
"Я с придурком"
"Придурок" (and the arrow points)

Comment: @OfftopicVoter: This is not a question "seeking words or phrases in English" - such questions usually look like "Как адекватно перевести на английский Мойдодыр?".

Answer (score 7):

Russian speakers usually *don't include themselves* into such an expression. The second meaning of it if written on a T-shirt ('my companion is stupid' or 'I accompany this psycho' - *этот придурок - со мной*) is lost here:

> этот придурок прав (= а ведь прав этот придурок)
>
> тупой, а соображает (= он хоть и тупой, а иногда соображает)

A bit *different* situation, but it is more typical in Russian to indulgently agree with a stupid person in *anything* they do or say:

> ... И не оспоривай глупца. (А.С. Пушкин, "Памятник")
>
> что с него (дурака) возьмёшь?!
>
> дуракам закон не писан

Comment: thanks for your answer, and the effort to make a gender neutral phrase! If this phrase in English was written on a shirt with a gender neutral background shirt color, the exact same shirt would be worn by men and women. I can see how making a gender neutral phrase in Russian would be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

if i get [the meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166704/why-does-im-with-stupid-have-a-positive-connotation) of the phrase, for example

> Я согласен с этим дурачком

the problem with this rendering is that it's not unisex

to circumvent this limitation a unisex pejorative may be used, but the adjective is still gender specific

> Я согласен с этим чучелом

a more wordy but gender neurtal version would be

> Мы единомышленники с этим чучелом

Comment: "мы единомышленники с этим чучелом" это почти по степени естественности звучания как славянский шкаф.

Comment: no wonder, it's an attempt at a translation of an idea absent in Russian discourse plus making it unisex which is uncharacteristic to Russian speech

Comment: I like the variant "Я согласен с этим чучелом". I think, there is no need to make the word "согласен" gender neutral, because it's unlikely that a man and a woman will wear *the same* T-shirt...  so one will just buy a T-shirt with a corresponding gender.

Answer (score 2):

I would translate: `Рядом с тупым` (I'm near a stupid person) or `Тупица рядом` (A stupid person is next to me), or even more succinct: `Тупица` (a dumb person), which is a slightly derogatory (but not overly offensive) word for a stupid person in Russian common language. For example, one could call their sibling `Тупица` to tease them and this won't be too inappropriate.

Comment: Yes, I always interpreted the statement as "сопровождаю дурака". I was surprised to see other answers interpreting it as "я согласен с дураком" or "я сторонник дурака". That is also a valid meaning in general for "I'm with [person]", but it doesn't really fit the context here. You're jokingly insulting the person standing or walking next to you as a prank (probably a friend or companion), but not intending to insult yourself by association.

Answer (score -2):

You could try an inscription like

> `Я - с этим ничтожеством`

While not equivalent to "stupid", this does convey a clearly negative opinion of the t-shirt wearer towards their companion, and is stronger in its wording than the original.

Closer to the original would be

> `Со мной - дур...`